# Can one intent match multiple intent-filters of same application?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Since an application can define same intent filter for different components of the application, it's very likely that intent would match multiple component for the same application. What will happened if it is the case? Will there be any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happened if it is the case?

Assuming that you are referring to `startActivity()`, then I would expect all matching activities from your app to appear in the chooser, along with any other activities on the device that match.

> Will there be any error?

Probably not. Note, however, that what you are describing is very unusual. Usually, an application only needs one activity to respond to any given `Intent` structure.

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable intent filter will catch the intent. From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html):

> A different strategy is needed for implicit intents. In the absence of a designated target, the Android system must find the best component (or components) to handle the intent — a single activity or service to perform the requested action or the set of broadcast receivers to respond to the broadcast announcement. It does so by comparing the contents of the Intent object to intent filters, structures associated with components that can potentially receive intents. Filters advertise the capabilities of a component and delimit the intents it can handle. They open the component to the possibility of receiving implicit intents of the advertised type. If a component does not have any intent filters, it can receive only explicit intents. A component with filters can receive both explicit and implicit intents.

...

> A filter has fields that parallel the action, data, and category fields of an Intent object. An implicit intent is tested against the filter in all three areas. To be delivered to the component that owns the filter, it must pass all three tests. If it fails even one of them, the Android system won't deliver it to the component — at least not on the basis of that filter. However, since a component can have multiple intent filters, an intent that does not pass through one of a component's filters might make it through on another.

In short: there will be no error. The system tries to find the best match for the intent, which may occasionally involve the user (think about when you install a new browser).